# Copying array onto the "this" variable (creating an Array-like object)

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to copy an array onto the this variable

```
function obj(arr) {
  for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; ++i) {
    this[i] = arr[i];
  }
  this.length = arr.length;
}

var o = new obj([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(o[0]); // Outputs 1
```

Is there any other way to do it, instead of iterating over the whole `arr` ?

Comment: You can refer following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: What is your use case for this?

Comment: @Rajesh the post you mentioned has nothing to do with my question

Comment: @MikeBrant Study purpose

Comment: My apologies then. I might have misunderstood it.

Comment: Dano the answer below is good. But I don't imagine why you need this. It's weird and dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) this way:

```
function obj(arr) {
  Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arr);
}
```

This will treat `this` like an array, adding all the elements from `arr` and setting `length` correctly. See also [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

But of course there is still an internal loop. You cannot copy / move a *collection* values to another collection without iterating over it (unless, I guess, the collections use [structural sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure))

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
function obj() {
    return this;
}

var o = obj.apply([1,2,3,4]);
console.log(o[0]); // Outputs 1
```

Comment: Are you aware that this simply returns the array itselft? is this a joke?

Comment: This doesn't do any *copying* which was clearly listed as a requirement.